# Pass Grid coordinates of winforms panel

Tags: c#, winforms

If I had an array of Panels in a 10 x 10 grid and I described each panels location with an x and y coordinate, how could I pass this to a Panel.click event?

```
int sqSize = 80;
int bAcross = 10;
CPanels = new Panel[bAcross, bAcross]; //10 * 10 grid

    for (int y = 0; y < bAcross; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bAcross; x++)
        {
            var newPan = new Panel
            {
                Size = new Size(sqSize, sqSize),
                Location = new Point(x * sqSize, y * sqSize)
            };

            Controls.Add(newPan);
            CPanels[x, y] = newPan; //add to correct location on grid
            newPan.Click += Pan_Click;
```

And what would I have to do in the click event?

```
private void Pan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = (extract x coord)
    int y = (extract y coord)
}
```

Edit : To clarify I am looking for the position in the grid. Basically the top left in the grid should be 0, 0 and the bottom right should be 10, 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Panel` that fired the `Pan_Click` event is available in the `sender` parameter:

```
private void Pan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = sender as Panel;
    if (panel == null)
        return;

    int x = panel.Location.X;
    int y = panel.Location.Y;
}
```

Since you actually want the location of the `Panel` in relation to the 10x10 grid, and since you're setting the location of each `Panel` by multiplying `sqSize` by the current location in the grid:

```
Location = new Point(x * sqSize, y * sqSize)
```

You can simply divide each coordinate by `sqSize` again, to get the original `x` and `y` values:

```
private void Pan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = sender as Panel;
    if (panel == null)
        return;

    int x = panel.Location.X / sqSize;
    int y = panel.Location.Y / sqSize;
}
```

(Also, note that if it's a 10x10 grid, the bottom-right corner will be 9,9 not 10,10)

Comment: Not sure if that is what he is wanting or to get the array coordinates that the panel is occupying

Comment: I was looking for something relative to the other panels (the grid). like the top left one should be 0, 0. And the bottom right should be 10, 10

Comment: @DavidN This answer should work for you, if you divide the Location.X and the Location.Y by your sqSize variable.